# Spring Cloud Kafka Streams Dynamic Message Conversion based on Header info

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud Kafka Streams to process messages off of a Kafka Topic that contains different types of messages. For instance, we receive a JSON message from the topic which can be either Type A or Type B message. The producer adds message type in the header, is there a way to Read that header info within the Functional Binder and convert the message accordingly? Or also is there a "Choice" option for branching as messages come in, to route the message to the right convertor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configure the binding to use `nativeDecoding`, the deserialzation is done by Kafka (via the `value.deserializer` consumer property).

spring-kafka provides a `JsonDeserializer` which looks for type information in specific headers (set by a corresponding `JsonSerializer`.

It also provides a `DelegatingDeserializer` which allows you to select which deserializer to use based on the value in a `spring.kafka.serialization.selector` header.

See [the Spring for Apache Kafka Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#serdes) for more information.